# Coding Style Standards for Android

Tags: android, coding-style, standards

I would like to know if there is some standard code styling for Android(maybe a book?) (styling XML , Java programming , file naming , etc...)

Answer (score 133, accepted):

There is a good description of code style rules [here](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html).

If you want to enforce this rules without remembering all of them, and you are using eclipse then you can use formatting rules provided by Android team:  [android-formatting.xml](https://raw.github.com/android/platform_development/master/ide/eclipse/android-formatting.xml). Just import it into eclipse using Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter, click Import.

Comment: Is something like this possible for Android Studio? If so, How do I enable it?

Comment: Android Studio hasn't build-in this?

Comment: @wyatt in Android Studio You can use this combination. CTRL + ALT + L for (Win/ Linux) & OPTION + CMD + L for (Mac)

Comment: Just want to point out that on Ubuntu, `CTRL + ALT + L` locks the screen. You may have to change the Key binding manually in Settings.

Comment: These rules (Code Style Guidelines for Contributors) are only for Java code. Is there anything similar for XML resources?

Comment: Where can I find a code style xml for Android studio? I see [AndroidStyle.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/android-5.1.1_r6/ide/intellij/codestyles/AndroidStyle.xml) file used by Android code base. However not sure if it corresponds to the code style guidelines mentioned on the site. Also it you know where I can find the `lint.xml` file adhering to these guidelines ?

Comment: This are rules for AOSP contributors! It's not a correct answer.

Answer (score 11):

There is a ton of information available here: 
http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html

Comment: Do you know where can we get the code style xml file or even lint file which follows these guidelines?

Answer (score 8):

@inazaruk: The codesearch link for android-formatting.xml is now obsolete. I found the file at [geobeagle](http://code.google.com/p/geobeagle/downloads/detail?name=android-formatting.xml).

Funny thing is that the file is also mentioned at android source ([Using Eclipse](http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html)) with no further linking :D (Most probably it was linking to the obsolete one).

One more file mentioned at android's Using Eclipse and [found at geobeagle](http://code.google.com/p/geobeagle/downloads/detail?name=android.importorder) ;-) is android.importorder.

(This should be a comment but I don't have 50pt yet :/ Sorry)

**Edit: March 2015**

As [Google Code is fading away](http://google-opensource.blogspot.gr/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html) you may find the two file at [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/denispyr/scrap/src/bf234373b354ee8b1f13f916f30431253017053b/eclipse/?at=master).

Answer (score 4):

please refer:

[https://www.fer.unizg.hr/*download/repository/ProjectConventions*-_Java_Android.pdf](https://www.fer.unizg.hr/_download/repository/ProjectConventions_-_Java_Android.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something like that and found [this](https://github.com/ribot/android-guidelines/blob/master/project_and_code_guidelines.md). We are using it combined with some of our own conventions. Very helpful.