# Is there any Android Coding Standard document available?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Coding Style Standards for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544769/coding-style-standards-for-android)

I am new to Android Development and curious if there is any Android Coding Standard document available.

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7544769/645270)

Comment: I don't think we need to follow separate coding standards for Android. As we are using java to develop Android apps, whatever standards are there for java, also apply to Android as in Chirag's link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is lot of information available here for coding standard.

http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html

Comment: This is coding standard for AOSP not for Android applications...

Answer (score 0):

You can find information of code styling: http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html

And for the rest: http://developer.android.com