# Android code design guidelines

Tags: android

I have been developing embedded software in C for a few years for which I have been taught to use a layered architecture and I got used to it. Recently I made a switch to Android (and Java) and I am wondering if a similar approach is in use. OOP is also pretty new to me so at some points I am struggling at making good design choices.
Are there any OFFICIAL design guidelines for the code of Android applications? I have seen a separation of activity and view related code, but I don't know if it is a good approach, and is something like this officially encouraged by Google.

Comment: "I am struggling at making good design choices." - just like the designers of the android framework! :-)

Comment: I think an MVC style is the way to go.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544769/coding-style-standards-for-android

Comment: Could someone point out to me why is this question still off-topic, even after my corrections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android is based  somehow in MCV paradigm. Basically, you define your views in xml files called layouts. Activities, fragments and widgets in a lower level let you control the functionality of your views. OOP is also present since you are able to define your own models.

Try to define all your views in XML files and take advance of OOP defining your own models related to Android (or custom) widgets. In activities and fragments you should implement all the listeners stuff and related.

Android developer has some great tutorials and guides: https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

Anyway, this is a very wide question that can be answered in many and valid ways.

Comment: Bit confusing here OOP is also present since you are able to define your own models.? Can you explain bit more? What can be models in the android?

Comment: Imagine a ListView with custom rows where you want to show, title, price and description of a book. By model i refer to create a Book class with at least title, price and description parameters, methods to calculate the price, to translate the description and the title... that's what i refer by model. Sorry for my english if it's not clear enough =)

Comment: I like your answer the most. I don't know what happens when I accept it after this question is marked as closed...

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend some of the links regarding to Patterns and UI :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4znvD-7VDA

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1ZBjlCRfz0

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html

http://www.androiduipatterns.com/

http://sealskej.blogspot.com/2010/11/ui-designing-for-android.html

Answer (score 1):

Its a really broad question that you have asked but in short i have three link which will definitely helps you.

You have ask about specially about design so [here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) is detail page about the resource and how you can use it in your application with different size.

- Things to be care while you [creating design](https://developer.android.com/design/index.html) of Android Application.
- Things to be care while you [writing code](https://developer.android.com/develop/index.html) of Android Application.
- Things to be care while you are ready to [publish Android Application](https://developer.android.com/distribute/index.html) in market.

[Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/index.html) is official website for android developer.

Answer (score 1):

First off, study main principles of Object Oriented Programming.
There is a great course on Lynda.com you can refer to. [link](http://www.lynda.com/Programming-tutorials/Foundations-of-Programming-Object-Oriented-Design/96949-2.html)

Then, having a deep understanding of what you're actually doing and why, it should be much easier to delve into Java and Android.